# Array of UILabels

Tags: ios, uilabel

I am developing an application and i want to create an array of UILabels. Can you please help me?

Should I create the labels writing code or I can use the interface builder?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You can do both. But if the number of labels is greater than - let's say - 6 creating them in code makes more sense (in my opinion).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this either in code or interface builder.  In interface builder, you can connect all the UILabels to a IBOutletCollection - obviously, in code, you can create and populate your own NSArray.

The IBOutletCollection property should look something like:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UILabel) NSArray *test;
```

Keep in mind that the array is not necessarily ordered in the same order that you connected the UILabels to it in IB.  If this is important, you should either sort the array as needed in `viewDidLoad` or opt to create your array manually.

Comment: Thanks Joseph, you really helped me!

Answer (score 1):

In IB, it would be most simple.  Such a structure is called an IBOutletCollection, and is exactly what you describe, an array of labels.